# how to add custom html attribute with fabric react nav component?

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I am using

```js
import { Nav } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
function CustomNav(props) {
  return <Nav groups={groups} selectedKey={selectedKey} onLinkClick={handleLinkClick} data-myTag="hello" />;
}
```

For nav object, I want to add custom html attributes such as `data-myTag`. How do I add this attribute to the button that is added to the DOM by this `Nav` object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on looking at the source [where `Nav` is rendered](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/96d987730064b7dbba4c785a3a1fa8c8f169958b/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Nav/Nav.base.tsx#L67), it unfortunately looks like it isn't possible to add data tags to the container.

Your best bet would likely be to either:

- Put the data attributes on a `div` you return from your `CustomNav` component, or
- Create a pull request with Fabric itself which renders those data attributes

Comment: You are partially correct. I found another approach by adding a custom button to the nav headers. This was suggested by my friend's colleague.